# What are typical power use, pressure, and volume for domestic dishwasher pumps

Tags: dishwasher, pump

I have just replace my dishwasher.  The walls (plastic) had a crack running the length of all 3 sides.  It's given us 15 year's service, so it has paid it's dues.

When I pulled it it was still working.  Occurs to me that the pump may be useful for other things.

What is the typical flow rate and volume of these pumps?  I found one manual on line for a replacement pump that listed 220v 88W 15 PSI, 60 liters/min  (~15 gal/min)

Is this typical?  Huge variation?  (I know that commercial ones use much higher pressure and volume.  The one in the restaurant I worked at took 90 seconds for a cycle, instead of the 2 hours for my home unit.)

Comment: If no one else knows, it sounds like you're in a great position to run some tests and tell us!

Comment: It is possible we could find out with the model #.

Comment: My application is such that I would start collecting them whenever I find an unwanted dishwasher.  Turn it around:  If you know one, give it's specs.  If you know a general source for multiple ones give that.  Right now I'm looking for typical values, not a specific model.